# Sharepoint 2010: How to programmatically update a RTF column with formattings

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, rtf

I've a RTF text field in a list.  Users can edit and format this column in many ways, and it also shows up with this formatting in views, which is very beautiful.

However, is it possible to update the RTF column somehow programmatically - e.g. within a workflow? My idea is to use the RTF column for creating formatted reports.

I already created a Workflow which automatically updates the RTF column, but so far, I'm only able to create plain text. No formatting, no new lines, etc. --- can anyone help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use html tags for your content.

**EDIT:**

```
item["RTF_Field"] = "<b>this is a strong text</b>";
```

Comment: Can you explain this further?

Comment: Wow, that works!! Thank you so much!! Now our reports are really looking great.

Comment: what about pictures?